# Python: using re.sub for ascii numbers coded as &#number;

Tags: python, regex, ascii

I have a text with some strange characters in it. For example, the word 'éxâmplë' might occur. But it is not shown as such, but as `&#130;x&#131;mpl&#137;`. Luckily, those numbers are coded ASCII, so I can use `chr()` for that. So, I want to replace `&#<number>;` by `chr(number)`.

I started using the `re` module for that, but as I'm not that experienced with that, I don't know how to. Below is my attempt, but of course, the code tries to convert the `int()` part to an int before doing the `re.sub()` part, raising a `ValueError`. How can I do this properly?

```
sentence = "This is an &#130;x&#131;mpl&#137;."
chrpatt = "&#([0-9]{3});"
sentence = re.sub(chrpatt, chr(int("\g<1>")), sentence)
print sentence
```

Comment: Where did you get these data from? It is very unusual for HTML to use the DOS codepages for encoding diacritical characters.

Comment: The data was read from a website using `urllib2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int("\g<1>")` gives you the ValueError here. `int` is the int constructor. If you gives this constructor a string, it expects to find a string that represents a number. Clearly, the string "\g<1>" does not look like the representation of a number.

The second argument of re.sub in your case should be a function that will take the match found and transform it.

Quote from the python documentation 
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.sub

> re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
>
> ...
>
> If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string. For example:

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use regular expressions here.

There is an entire library for this called `HTMlParser`.

**Example:**

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> h.unescape("This is an &#130;x&#131;mpl&#137;.")
u'This is an \x82x\x83mpl\x89.'
```

And just in case it wasn't clear before:

```
>>> chr(130)
'\x82'
>>> chr(131)
'\x83'
>>> chr(137)
'\x89'
```

*Don't re-invent the wheel*.

Comment: @Lewistrick You have got to be kidding right? ``print x`` where ``x`` is the result. e.g: ``x = h.unescape(s)`` *sigh*

Comment: @Lewistrick "It doesn't work" is a very very concise description about what happens...

Comment: Sorry, that was a very blunt way of expressing myself indeed. What I meant was: `print u'This is an \x82x\x83mpl\x89.'` returns a `UnicodeDecodeError` (character maps to <undefined>).

Comment: @Lewistrick As your example uses CP437 or CP850, `u'This is an \x82x\x83mpl\x89.'` is wrong. Instead, `u'This is an \xe9x\xe2mpl\xeb.'` would be right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callable parameter for `sub()`:

```
>>> import re
>>> sentence = "This is an &#130;x&#131;mpl&#137;."
>>> chrpatt = "&#([0-9]{3});"
>>> def rpl(m): return chr(int(m.group(1)))
>>> re.sub(chrpatt, rpl, sentence)
'This is an \x82x\x83mpl\x89.'
>>> print re.sub(chrpatt, rpl, sentence)
This is an éxâmplë.
```

Obviously, the data is encoded one of the DOS codepages (437 or 850): on my Linux system at home, I have to do

```
>>> print re.sub(chrpatt, lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1))) , sentence).decode("cp437")
This is an éxâmplë.
>>> re.sub(chrpatt, lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1))) , sentence).decode("cp437")
u'This is an \xe9x\xe2mpl\xeb.'
```

in order to get the right output.

What happens here?

For every match, the given function is passed the match object and is supposed to return the replacement string.

So we just do that - extract the number out of the match and perform the steps suggested by you.

Comment: This does exactly the same, right? `print re.sub(chrpatt, lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1))) , sentence)`

Comment: @Lewistrick Yes. Normally, I would have written this, but had to test a little bit and just forgot it.

Comment: ``>>> print "This is an \x82x\x83mpl\x89."
This is an �x�mpl�.``

Comment: @JamesMills Depends on the encoding you use.